# I can't execute a command

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I can't open my python file when I press the button I made. I think it has something to do with the "m" function I made.

```
def m():
    filename = "menu.py"
    f = open(filename)
    return f.read()

Menu = tk.Button(root, text="Menu", fg="white", bg="black", command=m)
Menu.pack()
```

I don't know much about **this** form of python programming.

Comment: How do you know that you can't open the file? (You know that "open the file" is something different from "open in an editor?)

Comment: don't forget close the file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Exactly what do you expect to happen when the button is clicked? Where the code says `return f.read()`, where do you expect it to be returned *to*?